# Hibernate autoupdate in single transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have two entities — `Person` and `Address` that have many-to-one relationship. So while trying to experiment with cascading and autoupdating i saw some interesting thing(for me):

```
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
        Address address = new Address("UK", "London", "221B Baker Street");
        Person person = new Person("Sherlock", "Homes", address);

        personRepository.save(person); //saves address also because of cascading

        address = addressRepository.findByCity("London");

        Set<Person> persons = address.getPersons();
        persons.add(new Person("John", "Watson", address)); //insert fires
        persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Morstan", address)); //nothing happens
    }
```

As you can see i get `Address` instance(previously saved) and add two new `Person`-s to it. What i expected is that Hibernate would update the `address` by inserting this `Persons`-s but it only updates the first one. Do anyone know what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT: initial answer was incorrect, here is correct one:*

After some discussion in comments we've found that author has overriden `equals` and `hashCode` in his objects. [Here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode) is article about this. Briefly: if we override we override `equals` and `hashCode` method based on `id` of entity — than when we add object to `Set` it has id of `null`, when we add second object - it has same id, so it's considered to be a duplicate and isn't being added to collection, and, consequently, isn't being persisted to DB.

Comment: Ok, this is my mappings: 
`Address` :
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();`
`Person` : 
`@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AddressId")
    private Address address;`
And about your answer — so what happens with a proxy after first call?

Comment: you define private  Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>(); which is pretty bad practice in hibernate: it can't handle any adds I think - it's not being proxied by hibernate. Are you sure that insert is emitted on first save?

Comment: Actually you don't need to use set at all, I think - you van just use List with `inverse="true"`. It won't fetch your collection at all until you really need this. Also you can use simple `addPerson` methos in address, which will internally do 2 things: `persons.add(person);` and `person.setAddress(this);`

Comment: What is bad in assigning `Set`? What if i want to add `Person`-s to `Address` when persisting it. I have to create an actual instance anyway. And you're wrong — `Set` actually being proxied. The proxy is `PersistentSet`, i checked it. Also i do want a `Set` not a `List`.

Comment: @Jskyi I'm wrong, sorry. You are free to downvote my answer, Still interesting if saving persons, not address works. I have some strange ideas about owner of relation…

Comment: Is it possible that you have overriden equals and hash code which causes to incorrectly think, that added objects are equal?

Comment: [Here is article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode) where authors are trying to add to elements to Set which is very similar to yours situation.

Comment: If you won't mind I'll update answer (actually delete old one and paste new one) for other people to more easily find correct solution.